# Intersection of cell array in MATLAB

Tags: arrays, matlab, cell, intersection

I need to determine intersection of all cells in array cell. I use a command like this:

```
temp(j-1)={6 7 8 9 10};
temp(j)= {8 9 10};

inter =  cellfun(@intersect,temp(j-1),temp(j),'UniformOutput', false)  ;
```

In the output I get:

```
inter={0189}
```

What should I do to get {8 9 10}?

I have to use inter as a vector of indexes in another matrix.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only way I can see that you would get something like `inter={0189}` is if, in fact, you are actually getting `inter=' 0189'` because your cells contain strings. If this is so, you can instead do the intersection like this:

```
>> temp = {'6 7 8 9 10' '8 9 10'}

temp = 

    '6 7 8 9 10'    '8 9 10'

>> inter = intersect(str2num(temp{1}), str2num(temp{2}))

inter =

     8     9    10
```

I have to ask though, why not store your data in numerical vectors instead of strings?

Comment: Hi, thanks for answer!  I had a problem with function unique(), so I tried to deal with this by converting num to str... it worked so it seemed to be ok... but of course you're right. I try to learn matlab actually, so thank you very much for your help.